# R: How to fix the datetime to always return a specified week's data in a time series data set?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, time-series

I am working on time series sensor data. 
Here is our process: There are 3 columns (EditDate, ID, InsertDate)

```
EditDate: This is date when the sensor data is edited/modified for that week 
ID: A manufacturing tool identifier
InsertDate: This is the date when all the sensor information will be added to the data frame at once for that week
```

We add the data every Friday at 6:30 am (InsertDate). My problem is to find outliers in the data for the last 7 days (Note: the original data frame will have data from the previous weeks too). While I am implementing my outlier function properly, I am messing up with the dates and which is where I need help.

For example consider this data frame

```
EditDate <- c("04/17/2015 5:46:23 AM", "04/17/2015 5:23:23 AM","04/16/2015 9:46:34 AM","04/15/2015 23:46:11AM","04/11/2015 11:46:17 AM","04/10/2015 6:34:23 AM","04/10/2015 6:29:34 AM","04/8/2015  5:46:12 AM","04/5/2015  5:46:22 AM","04/3/2015  6:31:22 AM","04/3/2015  6:29:23 AM")
ID <- c("DX154", "DX156","DX157","DX159","DX132,"DX137","DX111","DX123","DX136","DX051","DX021")
InsertDate <- c("4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM", "4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM","4/3/2015  6:30:00 AM")

df1 <- data.frame(EditDate , ID, InsertDate)
```

Output

```html
+------------------------+-------+----------------------+
|        EditDate        |  ID   |      InsertDate      |
+------------------------+-------+----------------------+
| 04/17/2015 5:46:23 AM  | DX154 | 4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/17/2015 5:23:23 AM  | DX156 | 4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/16/2015 9:46:34 AM  | DX157 | 4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/15/2015 23:46:11AM  | DX159 | 4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/11/2015 11:46:17 AM | DX132 | 4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/10/2015 6:34:23 AM  | DX137 | 4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/10/2015 6:29:34 AM  | DX111 | 4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/8/2015  5:46:12 AM  | DX123 | 4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/5/2015  5:46:22 AM  | DX123 | 4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/3/2015  6:31:22 AM  | DX123 | 4/10/2015 6:30:00 AM |
| 04/3/2015  6:29:23 AM  | DX123 | 4/3/2015  6:30:00 AM |
+------------------------+-------+----------------------+
```

Once I have the data frame, What I do is

```
BackAWeek <-Sys.time() - (604800*2) #604800 is a week in seconds
df2 <- subset(df1, df1$EditDate<BackAWeek)
df3 <- subset(df1, df1$EditDate>BackAWeek)
```

df2 contains last 7 days of data and df3 should contain all the data that are not part of the last week. The week in this sense is calculated based on Insert Date, which is (For ex: Suppose we have data for 4 weeks. The df2 should return all data from the Friday 6:30:00 AM of Week 3 to Friday 6:29:59 AM of Week 4).

My current script demands that I run it every Friday at 6:31:00 AM to get the data for the last 7 days, which is not possible in every time. Suppose When I run the script in the middle of next week (Say, Wednesday (4/22/15)) to look at the data, my script takes the current time and subtracts 7 days and because of this I miss any data that was entered before 4/15/15.

The data frame that I would be getting if I run the script on 4/22/15 is

```html
EditDate                 ID      InsertDate
04/17/2015 5:46:23 AM   DX154   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/17/2015 5:23:23 AM   DX156   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/16/2015 9:46:34 AM   DX157   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/15/2015 23:46:11AM   DX159   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
```

But the desired one is

```
EditDate                 ID     InsertDate
04/17/2015 5:46:23 AM   DX154   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/17/2015 5:23:23 AM   DX156   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/16/2015 9:46:34 AM   DX157   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/15/2015 23:46:11AM   DX159   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/11/2015 11:46:17 AM  DX132   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
04/10/2015 6:34:23 AM   DX137   4/17/2015 6:30:00 AM
```

Kindly provide inputs on how I can fix my code to always consider the Friday - Friday 6:30 am no matter what time I run it every week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably utilize standardized date strings and then convert them to actual time data types that R can work with. This tutorial can help you out with this: http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/time.html

A solution for your problem would be to look for the previous Friday and the Friday before that and then only utilize the data that matches the criteria.
For example:

First, Create your dataframe. Notice the leading '0' for the hours in the datestamp:

```
EditDate <- c("03/10/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/17/2015 05:46:23 AM", "04/17/2015 05:23:23 AM","04/16/2015 09:46:34 AM","04/15/2015 08:46:11 AM","04/11/2015 11:46:17 AM","04/10/2015 06:34:23 AM","04/10/2015 06:29:34 AM","04/8/2015 05:46:12 AM","04/5/2015  05:46:22 AM","04/3/2015 06:31:22 AM","04/3/2015 06:29:23 AM")
ID <- c("DX153","DX154", "DX156","DX157","DX159","DX132","DX137","DX111","DX123","DX136","DX051","DX021")
InsertDate <- c("03/10/2015 06:30:00 AM", "04/17/2015 06:30:00 AM", "04/17/2015 6:30:00 AM","04/17/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/17/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/17/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/17/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/10/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/10/2015 06:30:00 AM","4/10/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/10/2015 06:30:00 AM","04/3/2015 06:30:00 AM")
df1 <- data.frame(EditDate,ID,InsertDate)
```

Your date formats in the dataframe are now interpreted as integers:

```
> typeof(df1$EditDate[1])
[1] "integer"
> typeof(df1$EditDate[1])
[1] "integer"
```

You can convert the dates to a date format using the strptime function in order to obtain POSIXlt data types. Here, we will do it for both fields in one go using lapply:

```
df1[,c("EditDate","InsertDate")] <- lapply(df1[,c("EditDate","InsertDate")],strptime,format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

We get:

```
> typeof(df1$EditDate[1])
[1] "list"
```

As you can see the original strings you entered are now converted to a list. This list correponds to the POSIXlt data type. As an example:

```
> df1$EditDate[1]$hour
[1] 6
> df1$EditDate[1]$min
[1] 30
> df1$EditDate[1]$sec
[1] 0
```

Now, to find the latest friday we could start with the current timestamp and perform some manipulations to get the date you need:

```
lastFriday <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
lastFriday$mday <- lastFriday$mday + (lastFriday$wday-(lastFriday$wday+2))
lastFriday$hour = "6"
lastFriday$min = "30"
lastFriday$sec = "0"
```

To find the Friday the week before we could just subtract 7 days from the obtained timestamp. Note that the built in POSIXlt datatype makes this easy for the users and handles the underlying date/time logic.

```
fridayBefore <- lastFriday
fridayBefore$mday <- fridayBefore$mday-7
```

We get:

```
> lastFriday
[1] "2015-04-17 06:30:00 CEST"
> fridayBefore
[1] "2015-04-10 06:30:00 CEST"
```

The only thing we still need to do is fetch the part of the dataframe that contains the data with the relevant timestamps. We could for example just logically select the rows that we need

```
logicalVector <- (df1$InsertDate <= lastFriday & df1$InsertDate >= fridayBefore)
results <- df1[logicalVector,]
```

We get:

```
> results
              EditDate    ID          InsertDate
2  2015-04-17 05:46:23 DX154 2015-04-17 06:30:00
3  2015-04-17 05:23:23 DX156 2015-04-17 06:30:00
4  2015-04-16 09:46:34 DX157 2015-04-17 06:30:00
5  2015-04-15 08:46:11 DX159 2015-04-17 06:30:00
6  2015-04-11 11:46:17 DX132 2015-04-17 06:30:00
7  2015-04-10 06:34:23 DX137 2015-04-17 06:30:00
8  2015-04-10 06:29:34 DX111 2015-04-10 06:30:00
9  2015-04-08 05:46:12 DX123 2015-04-10 06:30:00
10 2015-04-05 05:46:22 DX136 2015-04-10 06:30:00
11 2015-04-03 06:31:22 DX051 2015-04-10 06:30:00
```